# Merge Solr Index with CoreAdmin Api

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, solr5

I am trying to merge solr indexes from multiple solr cores into a new core.
i am using coreAdmin api for this. but all i get is an empty response header with no error or success message.

Here is the api from solr Documentation.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=mergeindexes&core=NewCore&srcCore=Document&srcCore=Parts
```

after this i get this response

```
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
   </lst>
</response>
```

Please guide. how to successfully merge indexes from multiple cores.
I am using Solr 5.3

Here is the link for Mergin Indexes from Solr Documentation [MERGEINDEXES](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-MERGEINDEXES).

Comment: The `<int name="status">0</int>` means that your command successfully submitted to the solr and `<int name="QTime">0</int>` means that query time was zero for the command. Did you check the data (core), whether it got merged or not. May be it is (was) doing it in background.

Comment: I did check the core. it had not merged data. <int name="QTime">0</int> is practically not possible. it should take atleast <int name="QTime">1</int>.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also getting QTime 0 when trying this, and can't find any useful information on it..

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem. Official CoreAdminAPI doesn't say anything about new core. As per:

> https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MergingSolrIndexes

Your `NewCore` **must exist** and have a compatible schema with `Document` and `Parts`.